# Joomla 2.5 url shows two url with index.php and without

Tags: joomla, indexing

my url is http://www.clippingpathoutsource.com and it works fine but when I click to the logo of the page then the url shows http://www.clippingpathoutsource.com/index.php
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to identify the problem without looking at the code in the template file...

check the following:

1) In Template check index.php for below block of code

```
<div class="logoArea">
       <a href="/index.php">
```

2) Instead of "/index.php" in the href attribute of the a tag put your domain name.